How to use LLaVa embedding function? Multi-Modal Rag
I'm currently implementing a multi-modal RAG sys leveraging, LLaVa, Chroma & Langchain.
However, I'm having a hard time finding the embeddings function llava uses. Can anybody help me with that? Am I just blind?
Any pointers on how to narrow that down would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
I browsed through all files I could find after installing llava transformer through hugging face. I cannot find the code
